# ClassCastException in OptaPlanner due to a groupBy operation

Tags: java, classcastexception, optaplanner

I'm creating a school schedule generator and I'm getting an exception from one of my constraints which checks that all students have lunch breaks every day.

I'm using the constraint stream Java API. My constraint compiles (obviously) and looks like this:

```
public Constraint studentsShouldHaveLunchEveryDay(ConstraintFactory cf) {
    return cf.from(RecurringLecture.class)
            .filter(RecurringLecture::isScheduled)                     // [Lecture]...
            .groupBy(l -> l, l -> l.getCourseRound().getStudents())    // [Lecture, Set<Student>]...
            .flattenLast(students -> students)                         // [Lecture, Student]...
            .groupBy((l, s) -> s,                                      // [Student, Map<Day, Set<Lecture>>]...
                    ConstraintCollectors.toMap(
                            (l, s) -> l.getStartTimeslot().getDay(),
                            (l, s) -> l))
            //.flattenLast(Map::values)                                // [Student, Set<Lecture>]...
            //.filter((student, dailyLectures) -> !LunchBreakAnalyzer.hasLunchBreak(dailyLectures))
            .penalize(StudentLunchProblem.class.getName(), HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
}
```

I have temporarily commented out the `flattenLast` and `filter` for debugging reasons, and the problem still reproduces. If I comment out the last `groupBy` though, the issue does not seem to reproduce.

For some reason, the framework tries to cast a `Student` (`ImmutableStudent` to be precise) to an `Object[]`.

The line in the framework that throws is in `ArrayElementReader` and looks like this:

```
public Object getValue(InternalWorkingMemory workingMemory,
                       Object object) {
    Object[] array = (Object[]) this.arrayReadAccessor.getValue( workingMemory,
                                                                 object );
    return array[this.index];
}
```

The full exception looks as follows:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move thread with moveThreadIndex (1) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.get(SwingWorker.java:613)
    at vngschedules.ui.automation.AutomationPanel$1$1.done(AutomationPanel.java:44)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$5.run(SwingWorker.java:750)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.run(SwingWorker.java:847)
    at java.desktop/sun.swing.AccumulativeRunnable.run(AccumulativeRunnable.java:112)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$DoSubmitAccumulativeRunnable.actionPerformed(SwingWorker.java:857)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:317)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:249)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move thread with moveThreadIndex (1) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.take(OrderByMoveIndexBlockingQueue.java:147)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.forageResult(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:189)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.decider.MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.decideNextStep(MultiThreadedLocalSearchDecider.java:160)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.localsearch.DefaultLocalSearchPhase.solve(DefaultLocalSearchPhase.java:95)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.AbstractSolver.runPhases(AbstractSolver.java:99)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.solver.DefaultSolver.solve(DefaultSolver.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The move thread with moveThreadIndex (1) has thrown an exception. Relayed here in the parent thread.

    at vngschedules.ui.automation.SolverSwingWorker.doInBackground(SolverSwingWorker.java:29)
    at vngschedules.ui.automation.SolverSwingWorker.doInBackground(SolverSwingWorker.java:10)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker$1.call(SwingWorker.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingWorker.run(SwingWorker.java:343)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class vngschedules.schedule.ImmutableStudent cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; (vngschedules.schedule.ImmutableStudent is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.drools.core.base.extractors.ArrayElementReader.getValue(ArrayElementReader.java:162)
    at org.drools.core.base.extractors.ArrayElementReader.getValue(ArrayElementReader.java:279)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.KiePackagesBuilder.lambda$getBindingFunction$66de2761$1(KiePackagesBuilder.java:794)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaReadAccessor.getValue(LambdaReadAccessor.java:43)
    at org.drools.core.rule.Declaration.getValue(Declaration.java:257)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.AbstractAccumulator.extractValue(AbstractAccumulator.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class vngschedules.schedule.ImmutableStudent cannot be cast to class [Ljava.lang.Object; (vngschedules.schedule.ImmutableStudent is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; [Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.stream.drools.common.BiAccumulator.accumulate(BiAccumulator.java:55)
    at org.drools.core.rule.SingleAccumulate.accumulate(SingleAccumulate.java:96)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaGroupByAccumulate.accumulate(LambdaGroupByAccumulate.java:121)
    at org.drools.modelcompiler.constraints.LambdaGroupByAccumulate.accumulate(LambdaGroupByAccumulate.java:114)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.addMatch(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:736)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.doRightInserts(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:253)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.PhreakAccumulateNode.doNode(PhreakAccumulateNode.java:99)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.switchOnDoBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:586)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalBetaNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:555)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalNode(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:382)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.innerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:342)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evalStackEntry(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:240)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.outerEval(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:183)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleNetworkEvaluator.evaluateNetwork(RuleNetworkEvaluator.java:136)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.reEvaluateNetwork(RuleExecutor.java:235)
    at org.drools.core.phreak.RuleExecutor.evaluateNetworkAndFire(RuleExecutor.java:91)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.AbstractRuleEvaluator.internalEvaluateAndFire(AbstractRuleEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.drools.core.concurrent.SequentialRuleEvaluator.evaluateAndFire(SequentialRuleEvaluator.java:43)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireLoop(DefaultAgenda.java:869)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.internalFireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:816)
    at org.drools.core.common.DefaultAgenda.fireAllRules(DefaultAgenda.java:808)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.internalFireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1343)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1334)
    at org.drools.core.impl.StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.fireAllRules(StatefulKnowledgeSessionImpl.java:1326)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.stream.DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.calculateScore(DroolsConstraintStreamScoreDirector.java:90)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector.doAndProcessMove(AbstractScoreDirector.java:220)
    at org.optaplanner.core.impl.heuristic.thread.MoveThreadRunner.run(MoveThreadRunner.java:147)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    ... 3 more
```

I have commented out all other constraint streams in my program.

### Questions

1. Does this look like it's a fault in my code, or is it an issue with OptaPlanner?
2. If it's in my code, are there any tricks to debug this? I suspect that my constraint is compiled into Drools-something. Is there a way to skip this compilation, so that the exception can be traced back to my code? (As of now, no lines in the exception trace back to my code.)

Happy to provide more types if needed, but `RecurringLecture` is quite simple really, and `Student` is an Immutables interface compiled into an `ImmutableStudent`.

I'm using OptaPlanner 8.12.0.Final and Java 11.

### Update

I tried rewriting the constraint stream as follows:

```
public Constraint studentsShouldHaveLunchEveryDay(ConstraintFactory cf) {
    return cf.from(RecurringLecture.class)
            .filter(RecurringLecture::isScheduled)                     // [Lecture]...
            .groupBy(l -> l, l -> l.getCourseRound().getStudents())    // [Lecture, Set<Student>]...
            .flattenLast(students -> students)                         // [Lecture, Student]...
            .groupBy((l, s) -> ImmutableStudentAndDay.of(s, l.getStartTimeslot().getDay()),
                    ConstraintCollectors.toSet((l, s) -> l))
            .filter((student, dailyLectures) -> !LunchBreakAnalyzer.hasLunchBreak(dailyLectures))
            .penalize(StudentLunchProblem.class.getName(), HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
}
```

This avoids the `toMap` collector. I still run into the exact same issue however.

Comment: Would you mind providing an executable code reproducer, perhaps as a Github repo? This looks like a bug.

Comment: Github repo with minimal reproducer here: https://github.com/aioobe/optaplanner-class-cast-issue/tree/master/vng-schedule

Command I used to test repro: `./gradlew run -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/home/aioobe/bin/jdks/jdk-11 2>&1 | egrep "ClassCastEx|FIRING_ALL_RULES"` Unfortunately it may take 5-10 runs for it to throw the ClassCastException, but when it hits it, it hits it immediately, so you can run the command for just a few seconds before killing it / retrying.

Comment: Thanks for the reproducer, will look into it when time permits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if your constraint compiles and the code still throws `ClassCastException` at runtime, you should expect the bug to be on the OptaPlanner side. Unless you are willing to look at the Drools executable model, there is nothing for you to debug there.

I recommend refactoring the constraint to look like this:

```
public Constraint studentsShouldHaveLunchEveryDay(ConstraintFactory cf) {
    return cf.from(RecurringLecture.class)
        .filter(RecurringLecture::isScheduled)
        .join(Student.class,
              Joiners.filtering((l, s) -> l.getCourseRound().getStudents().contains(s)))
        .groupBy((l, s) -> ImmutableStudentAndDay.of(s, l.getStartTimeslot().getDay()),
                ConstraintCollectors.toSet((l, s) -> l))
        .filter((student, dailyLectures) -> !LunchBreakAnalyzer.hasLunchBreak(dailyLectures))
        .penalize(StudentLunchProblem.class.getName(), HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
}
```

I expect this to perform much better, possibly also getting rid of the exception. Regardless, the exception is still a problem and I will investigate it further if you provide your simplified executable reproducer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try this next. However, `Student` is not a special class (entity, or fact, or anything like that). Can it still be used in `join(...)`?

Comment: Ok, error message when trying the above confirmed that. Since the set of student objects is fixed, perhaps I should make student a planning fact? Is it reasonable practice to make a class a fact for the sole purpose of optimizing constraints? Or does it have other drawbacks?

Comment: Yes, you should make Student a problem fact. That's exactly the point of problem facts - to be able to introduce them into constraints. Since problem facts never change, it should have no performance impact on your solver, but the impact on constraint performance should be significant. (Assuming that contains() is O(1), not O(n).)

Comment: Glad to help. I filed a JIRA for the bug: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2565